# How to get a value and label in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function radioVal(){
    //var radVal = document.mainForm.rads.value;
 var radVal = document.getElementsByName("rads").value;
    result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal;
}
```

```html
<div class="pres">
  <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="rads" value="10" checked />
  <label for="radio01" class="dis"><span>1 time service</span></label>
</div>

<div class="pres">
  <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="rads" value="20" />
  <label for="radio02" class="dis"><span>Every week</span></label>
</div>

<div class="pres">
  <input type="radio" id="radio03" name="rads" value="15" />
  <label for="radio03" class="dis"><span>Every 2 weeks </span></label>
</div>

<div class="pres">
  <input type="radio" id="radio04" name="rads" value="10" />
  <label for="radio04" class="dis"><span>Every 4 weeks</span></label>
</div>

<input type="text" value="" id="result" name="perce" />
<input type="text" value="" id="txtservV" name="servicename" />
<input type="text" value="" id="final_pay" name="final_pay" />
```

Hello i am using this function to get the value of a selected radio button in a textfield name **perce** and its value in a field name **servicename** any one help me in it to sourt it out. I am using this function in doucument.ready function.

Comment: Please clarify the problem. I'm not sure how to help you 'in it to sourt it out' however, it would appear that the function returns an array, while you're trying to access the .value property of that array.. obviously the property doesn't exist.. access the *first element* of the array with [0]

Comment: For example i had selected the first radio button whose name is '' 1 time service '' and i need to show the checked name means "1 time service" in a servicename textbox and a value "10" in a perce textbox

Answer (score 1):

Use [Document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) function which returns array of elements (or better collection, array-like object), so that you can access value of input by index (0 in your case):

```
var perceVal = document.getElementsByName("perce")[0].value
```

In case of radio buttons you have to iterate through elements and find which one is checked:

```
var rads = document.getElementsByName("rads");
var radsValue;
for (var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++) {
    if (rads[i].checked) {
        radsValue = rads[i].value // here is checked radio
        break;
    }
}
```